# How to do a grouping(or range query) in Solr facet

Tags: solr, facet

All:

**[UPDATE]** Thanks for Andrea's answer, currently I am using this way:

> If you send also a **facet.mincount=1** then the start bound is just an
> indication because Solr will **return only those values** (i.e. ranges)
> that have at least 1 document inside. So for instance you could
> indicate a very low value as start.

Note: This is only proved works for my case, so use your judgement

`&facet=true&facet.range=createDate&facet.range.gap=%2B2DAY&facet.range.end=NOW&facet.range.start=NOW-1000DAY&facet.mincount=1`

---

I am pretty new to Solr facet. Suppose that I have some documents which has createDate:

```
"2015-03-23T17:59:00Z",
"2015-03-23T22:13:00Z",
"2015-03-17T20:48:00Z",
"2015-03-19T17:43:00Z",
"2015-03-19T21:58:00Z",
"2015-03-16T19:13:00Z",
"2015-03-16T22:26:00Z",
"2015-03-13T21:33:00Z",
"2015-03-13T21:39:00Z",
"2015-03-13T23:27:00Z",
"2015-03-16T16:46:00Z",
"2015-03-18T17:44:00Z",
"2015-03-18T18:10:00Z",
"2015-03-18T18:11:00Z"
.......
```

My questions are :

> [1] How to get the result range by DAY?
>
> [2] How to get facet result grouped by WEEK( or let us say 7 days)?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called range faceting. I suggest you to read the Solr wiki but in the meantime:

facet.range=(field name)
facet.range.start=(start date or value)
facet.range.end=(end date or value)
facet.range.gap=(interval value or expression)

In your case you should use +1DAY or +7DAYS as facet.range.gap.
There are also other parmeters so it's better if you have a look at the wiki

Comment: Thanks, but I do not quite understand how did you get the date range from this query?

Comment: from the wiki, it seems the face.range parameter is to specify which field to search rather than get value from facet.range.start

Comment: Yes sorry my response was escaped

Comment: Thanks for clear that, but I still not get how did you get the start date part. When I look at those dates, there is no way for me to know what to give to facet.range.start, what I want to give to facet.range.start is the min value among all those date. But how can I specify that in my query?

Comment: If you send also a facet.mincount=1 then the start bound is just an indication because Solr will return only those values (i.e. ranges) that have at least 1 document inside. So for instance you could indicate a very low value as start.

Comment: As an alternative you could issue a previous query requesting the minimum indexed value for that date, but I would try with the previous way before

Comment: The first way seems interesting, could you give a query example of it?

Comment: q=*:*&facet.range=createDate&facet.range.start=2000-01-10T17:00:00Z& facet.range.end=2010-01-10T17:00:00Z facet.range.gap=+1MONTH&facet.mincount=1

Comment: Sorry wrong copy and paste but i m not able to edit the comment